# Elliptical references in Python records

Tags: python, records, recordtype

Are elliptical references allowed in Python?

In an elliptical reference,the field is named, but any or all of the enclosing record names can be omitted,as long as the resulting reference is unambiguous in the referencing environment.

Could you provide me with some short examples..thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do elliptical references on normal data objects in Python because "Explicit is better than implicit" according to [the Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

However, you can do things like

```
from mymodule import Myclass
thing = Myclass()
```

instead of

```
import mymodule
thing = mymodule.Myclass()
```

---

While elliptical referencing *can* make code more succinct, in practice it can actually impede code readability since you need to figure out whether the reference is a simple name or an abbreviated reference, and when writing code you have to guard against accidentally creating an ambiguous reference. Also, handling such references makes the compiler's or interpreter's job harder. So even in languages that allow elliptical referencing it may be wise to avoid using them - many JavaScript programmers avoid the `with` construction for this reason.

In Python, we really don't need elliptical referencing, since we can easily bind a name at any level of a deeply-structured object.

Eg, instead of

```
a = some.deeply.structured.thing[5]['items'][0]
b = some.deeply.structured.thing[5]['items'][7]
c = some.deeply.structured.thing[5]['items'][11]
```

we can do

```
ref = some.deeply.structured.thing[5]['items']
a = ref[0]
b = ref[7]
c = ref[11]
```

Etc

For an excellent article on name binding in Python, please see [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.